# EJB/JPA: How to use EntityManager.persist() to always INSERT a new record, not update

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

EntityManager.persist() function is trying to update a existing record, but I always need  to **insert** a new one. How to achieve this?

Part of Entity bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SYNC_TRIGGER", schema="ETL")
public class SyncTrigger implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TRIGGER_SEQ", sequenceName = "ETL.TRIGGER_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TRIGGER_SEQ")
    private Long triggerId;
......
```

Part of Stateless bean, which persists the record:

```
@Stateless
public class TriggerPersister {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="syncTriggerDS") 
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public <T extends GenericTrigger> void persistTrigger(SyncTrigger 
            st, T concreteTrigger){

            entityManager.persist(st);
.........
```

UPD:
Before entityManager.persist(st) is executed st.triggerId value is null, but after - id of previously added record is assigned to this field.

Comment: You want update or insert? Your question title and content is not saying same thing.

Comment: To insert - persist(), to update - merge(). Merge() is for detached objects, for persistent you do nothing before committing a transaction.

Answer (score 3):

[`EntityManager.persist()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist%28java.lang.Object%29) always tries to create a new managed object. It throws an `EntityExistsException` if you call it on an already managed entity.

You'd have to use `merge()` for updates.

See the javadoc for both methods.

Comment: It's strange, but after entityManager.persist(st) gets executed triggerId is populated with ID of previously added record and nothing is added or updated in database. And no any exceptions are thrown. I need this ID later, to insert a referenced record to another table.

Comment: Maybe it's worth looking into the trigger?