# How to construct an insert query in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I am trying to insert data into a table having columns **(NAME, VALUE)** with

```
Query query = em.createQuery("INSERT INTO TestDataEntity (NAME, VALUE) VALUES (:name, :value)");
query.setParameter("name", name);
query.setParameter("value", value);
query.executeUpdate();
```

and getting the following exception:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:42: unexpected token: VALUES
```

Also, I cannot insert a record using a native query either:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO TEST_DATA (NAME, VALUE) VALUES (:name, :value);");
query.setParameter("name", name);
query.setParameter("value", value);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Another exception is being thrown:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

**The question is:**

- What is wrong with the query string?

Many thanks.

Comment: In JPA you Setup objects and uses the entitymanagers persist method to save them

Comment: @Jens: If I do select or update or delete similar to the above, everything is executed as they should be, then what's wrong with this query?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085716/jpa-insert-statement) answers your question ( Google jpa insert)

Comment: @Jens: Thanks for the link. I was thinking, that maybe there is no insert in hibernate, but I cannot insert a record via a native query either :(.

Comment: You can if you use `em.createNativeQuery`

Comment: @Jens: I tried it, but with no result :) Otherwise, I wouldn't write this question.

Comment: What was the Problem with nativeQuery?

Comment: @Jens: another exception is thrown mentioned in the updated question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141439/discussion-between-jens-and-armine).

Comment: This your query must remove last semicolon. @Armine

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I solved the issue.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3085782/6280998),

> There is no INSERT statement in JPA.

But I could solve the issue with native query: I have mistakenly put a redundant ; at the end of the query, so the issue solved by removing it.

Answer (score 3):

I found two examples where the author uses the insert in a native query ([first](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/NativeInsertStatementWithParameter.htm) and [second](https://www.codemiles.com/jpa/insert-using-native-query-t6205.html)). Then, your query could be:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("INSERT INTO TestDataEntity (NAME, VALUE) VALUES (?, ?)");
query.setParameter(1, name);
query.setParameter(2, value);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Try this.

Comment: As I have mentioned in my answer, I was able to insert data into the table with the native query. There was another problem: a redundant ";" was at the end of the query and that was causing the problem. Once I removed it, the native query worked as expected. Anyway, thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using the below - I just had a Table name Bike with 2 fields id and name . I used the below to insert that into the database.

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO Bike (id, name) VALUES (:id , :name);");
em.getTransaction().begin();
query.setParameter("id", "5");
query.setParameter("name", "Harley");
query.executeUpdate();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: I doubt if you really could run the code as it is written in your case without exception since there is redundant semicolon - ';' which prevents the successful run.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead.

Getting the above exception when start using begin() and commit().

Comment: 1st semicolon - end of the query and the next is to end the statement . This actually worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For manually created queries, we can use the EntityManager#createNativeQuery method. It allows us to create any type of SQL query, not only ones supported by JPA. Let's add a new method to our repository class:

```
@Transactional
public void insertWithQuery(Person person) {
    entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO person (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?,?)")
      .setParameter(1, person.getId())
      .setParameter(2, person.getFirstName())
      .setParameter(3, person.getLastName())
      .executeUpdate();
}
```

With this approach, we need to define a literal query including names of the columns and set their corresponding values.