# JPA Hibernate - Can't persist and executeUpdate query in same Entity Transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have been trying to persist an entity instance and then right after that
update that same entity instance through a JPQL query.
Both operations participate in a Entity Transaction, but after the commit,
the Update query seems to not have been executed or to have been executed before the commit.

How to get it right?

**Code:**

```
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();

    Person person = new Person();
    person.setAge(25);
    person.setName("John Ive");
    em.persist(person);

    Query q = em.createQuery("Update Person p set p.age=27 where p.personId=:id");
    q.setParameter("id",person.getPersonId());
    q.executeUpdate();
    transaction.commit();
```

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int personId;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    //Getters and setter here
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="example-db" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>example.entities.Person</class>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction" />
        <property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="commit" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Hibernate logs:

```
    08:27:42.847 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - begin
    08:27:42.854 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - call next value for hibernate_sequence
    Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
    08:27:42.860 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStructure - Sequence value obtained: 1
    08:27:42.860 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
    08:27:42.863 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier: 1, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator
    08:27:42.881 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
    08:27:42.882 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
        08:27:42.885 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
        08:27:42.885 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
        08:27:42.888 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
        08:27:42.888 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - example.entities.Person{name=John Ive, personId=1, age=25}
        08:27:42.896 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into Person (age, name, personId) values (?, ?, ?)
        Hibernate: insert into Person (age, name, personId) values (?, ?, ?)
        08:27:42.913 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator - QueryTranslatorFactory : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory@615f972
        08:27:42.913 [main] INFO org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
        08:27:42.942 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - parse() - HQL: Update example.entities.Person p set p.age=27 where p.personId=:id
        08:27:42.952 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - --- HQL AST ---
         \-[UPDATE] Node: 'Update'
            +-[FROM] Node: 'FROM'
            |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
            |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
            |     |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
            |     |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'example'
            |     |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'entities'
            |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'Person'
            |     \-[ALIAS] Node: 'p'
            +-[SET] Node: 'set'
            |  \-[EQ] Node: '='
            |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
            |     |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'p'
            |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'age'
            |     \-[NUM_INT] Node: '27'
            \-[WHERE] Node: 'where'
               \-[EQ] Node: '='
                  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
                  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'p'
                  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'personId'
                  \-[COLON] Node: ':'
                     \-[IDENT] Node: 'id'

        08:27:42.952 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
        08:27:42.992 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker - update << begin [level=1, statement=update]
        08:27:43.015 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement - FromClause{level=1} : example.entities.Person (p) -> person0_
        08:27:43.017 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved : p -> personId
        08:27:43.020 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode - getDataType() : age -> org.hibernate.type.IntegerType@309e345f
        08:27:43.022 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved : p.age -> age
        08:27:43.028 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved : p -> personId
        08:27:43.028 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode - getDataType() : personId -> org.hibernate.type.IntegerType@309e345f
        08:27:43.028 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved : p.personId -> personId
        08:27:43.031 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker - update : finishing up [level=1, statement=update]
        08:27:43.032 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker - update >> end [level=1, statement=update]
        08:27:43.033 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - --- SQL AST ---
         \-[UPDATE] UpdateStatement: 'Update'  querySpaces (Person)
            +-[FROM] FromClause: 'FROM' FromClause{level=1, fromElementCounter=1, fromElements=1, fromElementByClassAlias=[p], fromElementByTableAlias=[person0_], fromElementsByPath=[], collectionJoinFromElementsByPath=[], impliedElements=[]}
            |  \-[FROM_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'Person' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=p,role=null,tableName=Person,tableAlias=person0_,origin=null,columns={,className=example.entities.Person}}
            +-[SET] SqlNode: 'set'
            |  \-[EQ] BinaryLogicOperatorNode: '='
            |     +-[DOT] DotNode: 'age' {propertyName=age,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=age,path=p.age,tableAlias=person0_,className=example.entities.Person,classAlias=p}
            |     |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'personId' {alias=p, className=example.entities.Person, tableAlias=person0_}
            |     |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'age' {originalText=age}
            |     \-[NUM_INT] LiteralNode: '27'
            \-[WHERE] SqlNode: 'where'
               \-[EQ] BinaryLogicOperatorNode: '='
                  +-[DOT] DotNode: 'personId' {propertyName=personId,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=personId,path=p.personId,tableAlias=person0_,className=example.entities.Person,classAlias=p}
                  |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'personId' {alias=p, className=example.entities.Person, tableAlias=person0_}
                  |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'personId' {originalText=personId}
                  \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=id, expectedType=org.hibernate.type.IntegerType@309e345f}

        08:27:43.033 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
        08:27:43.048 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
        08:27:43.066 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - update Person set age=27 where personId=?
        Hibernate: update Person set age=27 where personId=?
        08:27:43.068 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - committing
08:27:43.069 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
08:27:43.069 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
08:27:43.069 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
08:27:43.070 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
```

Comment: try to use `em.flush();` after the persist

Comment: I see you have activated the config "show_sql". Can you send the sql's executed?

Comment: You can now see the sql

Comment: The insert statement is not executed. If you want make an update of the same Person, first must exists. Or try to use em.merge(person) instance of JPQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();

Person person = new Person();
person.setAge(25);
person.setName("John Ive");
em.persist(person);

person.setAge(27);
em.merge(person);

transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Are you telling me that the Update instruction is not supposed to work? Is it supposed to be executed on commit or not???

Comment: You are using distinct objects to make operations in database and it is possible that your Person has not the Id to do the update

Comment: Hi @Alberto, should I assume that it’s not possible to update an entity instance via a query in the same transaction it is created?

Comment: Yes should, but use jpql or entityManager to do the insert and update, but don't mixed. I think that is the problem. As you can see in logs, statements are executed by differents objects of hibernate

Comment: Based on this assumption, EntityManager.merge is the only option left. As long as the same EntityManager instance used for persist is used.

Comment: Or use jpql for insert: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347602/how-to-construct-an-insert-query-in-jpa

Answer (score -1):

Try entitymanager.refresh(). It worked for me